# Fire onCheckChanged event of CheckBox from jQuery aspnet

Tags: jquery, checkbox, oncheckedchanged

I have a CheckBox field in a GridView in an aspnet webform. Upon user checking / unchecking each checkbox, I want to run server side code for OnCheckedChanged event for that checkbox using jQuery.

The GridView loads in a jQuery popup window like this

```
<div id="dialog" style="display: none">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnPageIndexChanging="OnPageIndexChanging" DataKeyNames="ID"
        PageSize="10" AllowPaging="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:checkbox id="chk" runat="server" Text="Select" OnCheckedChanged="OnCheckChanged" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" ItemStyle-Width="100" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name" ItemStyle-Width="300" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" ItemStyle-Width="400" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

jQuery is like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input:checkbox").click(function () {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).trigger('OnCheckChanged',true);            
        } else {
            alert("false");
        }
    });
});
```

My "CheckChanged" Event is like this

```
Sub OnCheckChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
Dim chk As CheckBox = TryCast(sender, CheckBox)
Dim row As GridViewRow = TryCast(chk.NamingContainer, GridViewRow)
Dim pk As String = GridView1.DataKeys(row.RowIndex).Values(0).ToString
If chk.Checked = True Then
      'Do something  
Else
      'Do something 
End If

End Sub
```

The jQuery function works when the CheckBox is unchecked. But it does not fire the server side OnCheckChanged event

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("input[type=checkbox]" ).click(function () {
       if ($(this).is("input:checked")) {
           $(this).trigger('OnCheckChanged',true);            
       } else {
           alert("false");
       }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but it still does not fire the server side code.

Comment: The GridView loads in a jQuery popup window, as shown in the edit

Comment: Thanks for the comments

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions. After reading up a loooot, I came to the conclusion that I am required to use .trigger('change'), and not ,trigger('OnCheckChanged'). Please correct me if I am wrong.

Also, I have to include AutoPostBack="true" for the checkbox field. If I don't set this to "true", the server side event "OnCheckChanged" is not attached the checkbox at the time of rendering.

Now the issue is, when I set the AutoPostBack="true", the modal popup window disappears, and does not reload.

Is there any way to 
(a)  Attach the server side event to the control without setting AutoPostBack ="true"?

(b) Alternatively, can I reload the modal popup window after the postback, with the checkboxes in the same state as the user had selected?